# D3 time.parse with colon in time-zone format

Tags: date, parsing, d3.js, time

I'm trying to use d3.time.format on a date like this:

`2016-02-10T12:40:16-05:00`

Basically, a UTC date with a timezone offset.

The issue is, the `%Z` formatter in D3 looks for the timezone written as follows: `-0500`. In other words, the colon is missing.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: You could preprocess the string and remove the last colon.

Comment: Fwiw, this is fixed in d3 4.0